# what's the best practice of long running azure cosmos db server side script

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have a scenario that I need to loop through a big set of time series data like stock ticker and apply my algo in each tick. The algo is based on the time sequence so I can't use big data like spark to parallel processing.

if the stock tick set is big (say 10K), then it will take quite sometime for the algo to finish.

I plan to use the server side javascript of cosmos db to implement my algo, how should I handle the time out here?

I read that it will timeout after every 5 second and I need to keep retrying. Is that true?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid this is by design.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/programming#bounded-execution for how to handle this from code.

Hope this help